# What to do with the avot-patriarch-fathers tag?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Well, it was bound to happen: [someone's created](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31682) the [abraham](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abraham) tag. So do we go through all 116 [avot-patriarch-fathers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avot-patriarch-fathers) questions now, splitting them up into [abraham](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abraham), [isaac](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/isaac), and [jacob](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jacob), and retaining it only for questions about all three? Or do we split it up and not keep it at all (questions about all three can have three tags)? Or do we merge [abraham](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abraham) into [avot-patriarch-fathers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avot-patriarch-fathers)? Or what? Please post suggestions as answers. This question makes no specific suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If there are only 116 questions in the tag now, and we assume that some of them are about the avot in general and not specific avot, then I propose keeping the tag as-is and creating synonyms for the individual avot.  This facilitates searching for specific av-related topics.

Answer (score -2):

I think we should create [isaac](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/isaac) and [jacob](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jacob) tags and split up the [avot-patriarch-fathers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avot-patriarch-fathers) questions into the three other tags, so people who wish to find questions about (say) Abraham can do so without sifting through questions about the others.

Only a question that's about the threesome as a threesome (not about the three individuals) should retain the [avot-patriarch-fathers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avot-patriarch-fathers) tag, and only if there are enough of them to make such a tag worthwhile (more than three, perhaps). If the [avot-patriarch-fathers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avot-patriarch-fathers) is retained, its tag wiki should clarify that it should not be used for questions about specific patriarchs.

Comment: If I wanted to find questions about (say) Avraham, though, I'd probably use search, not just tags.  Questions about parshiyot in which he figures prominently might not be tagged as avot, after all.